# Firebase and angularfire token login

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

So trying to get basic token Auth working with angularfire. After login my page passes in a firebase token. This is what I have in angular:

```
var firetoken = mypassinvalue; //firebase token generated after login
var myApp = angular.module("MyApp", ["firebase", 'ngRoute']);
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            template: '<h2> this is home</h2>',
            controller: 'menuCtrl',
            });

        $routeProvider.when('/allocations', {
            template: '<h2> this is allocations</h2>',
            controller: 'menuCtrl'
            });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/lost'});
        }])

myApp.controller("menuCtrl", ["$scope", "$firebaseAuth", function($scope, $firebaseAuth) {
        var ref = new Firebase("https://mybase.firebaseio.com/");
        $scope.auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
        auth.$login(firetoken).then(function(user) {
            console.log('Logged in as: ', user);
            }, function(error) {
            console.error('Login failed: ', error);
            });
        }]);
```

So the error i'm getting on load is "TypeError: undefined is not a function" on this line: $scope.auth = $firebaseAuth(ref); Just trying to use what I found on http://angularfire.com/documentation.html

Comment: First of all you forgot to add the minsafe versions of $location and $firebaseAuth to your menuCtrl
It should be ["$scope", "$firebase", "$locate", "$firebaseAuth", function OR even better delete the unused arguments in the function. ($locate & $firebase)

Comment: Cleaned it up still have: ReferenceError: auth is not defined in the console.

Comment: Do you just need $scope.auth.$login instead of auth.$login?

Comment: As Zach pointed out, you're assigning $firebaseAuth() to $scope.auth, but trying to access it from simply `auth`.

Comment: Hate to admit it but yep that was my mistake. Doh. Does anyone have a link where I can read more on the minsafe versions thing? I don't remember reading it on angularjs.org